# kafka server: Config file not found error

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to run kafka server on ubuntu(16) with  java  `openjdk version "9-internal"` by following [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_kafka/apache_kafka_installation_steps.htm)  tutorial and when i run

`bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties`

to start Kafka(`kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0`) server i get following error

> Error: Config file not found: /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/conf/management/management.properties

I have checked there is no `java-9-openjdk-amd64/conf`

Please guide me  how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 7):

I found a `management/management.properties` file under `/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/lib` so my solution was to do:

```
cd /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64
sudo ln -s lib conf
```

which seems to have worked so far, but I'm unsure if there will be future ill effects.  It seems to me to be a packaging bug of some sort in the JDK.
`

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and solved by using java openjdk version "1.8.0_162".